# Flink - Kafka Connector EXACTLY ONCE error

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Flink 1.15.0. For Kafka integration I wrote

KafkaSource:

```
public static KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource(String bootstrapServers, String topic, String groupId) {
    return KafkaSource.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers)
            .setTopics(topic)              
            .setGroupId(groupId)                
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .build();
```

and KafkaSink:

```
public static KafkaSink<WordCountPojo> kafkaSink(String brokers, String topic, Properties producerProperties) {
    return KafkaSink.<WordCountPojo>builder()
            .setKafkaProducerConfig(producerProperties)
            .setBootstrapServers(brokers)
            .setRecordSerializer(new WordCountPojoSerializer(topic))
            .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
            .setTransactionalIdPrefix(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
}
```

for completeness this is my custom serializer

```
public class WordCountPojoSerializer implements KafkaRecordSerializationSchema<WordCountPojo> {
    private String topic;
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public WordCountPojoSerializer(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(WordCountPojo wordCountPojo, KafkaSinkContext kafkaSinkContext, Long timestamp) {
        try {
            byte[] serializedValue = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(wordCountPojo);
            return new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null,  timestamp,null, serializedValue);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Property `transaction.timeout.ms` is set to 60_000ms (1 minute)

My application run for a while, then, suddenly, stop with the exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
```

It seems that producer tries to produce record between two transaction, but I'm not sure.
I could increase transaction.timeout.ms to max 900_000 (15 minute) but I don't think this may solve the problem.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Kafka offsets and transactions are usually committed when the application performs a checkpoint. Could it be that checkpoint interval is set to more than 1 minute and thus, when it tries to commit, it fails due to the transaction having timed out?